# Acquire::By-Hash apt option does not work

Tags: apt

I'm trying to make apt-get use [`Acquire::By-Hash option`](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Format#Acquire-By-Hash), so it will download packages identifying them by cryptographic hash, not by package version. This should prevent race conditions and "Hash Sum Mismatch" errors happening sometimes while trying to apt-get install something.

I can't make apt-get use this method. I tried

1. Putting `Acquire::By-Hash "force";` to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51acquire_by_hash`
2. Changing sources.list:
   `deb [by-hash=force] http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free`
3. Using `-o Acquire::by-hash=force` apt-get option
   Neither works. apt-get still uses the old method (see the URLs it's requesting)

```
# apt-get -o Acquire::by-hash=force -o Debug::Acquire::http=true install fortunes
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fortunes
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,117 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,611 kB of additional disk space will be used.
0% [Working]GET /debian/pool/main/f/fortune-mod/fortunes_1.99.1-7_all.deb HTTP/1.1
Host: ftp.us.debian.org
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.8.2.1)


0% [Waiting for headers]Answer for: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/fortune-mod/fortunes_1.99.1-7_all.deb
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 09 Aug 2020 05:28:00 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Aug 2013 03:54:21 GMT
ETag: "110cf4-4e3f46de0807d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1117428

Get:1 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 fortunes all 1:1.99.1-7 [1,117 kB]
Fetched 1,117 kB in 18s (60.6 kB/s)                                                                                                              
Selecting previously unselected package fortunes.
(Reading database ... 159825 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fortunes_1%3a1.99.1-7_all.deb ...
Unpacking fortunes (1:1.99.1-7) ...
Setting up fortunes (1:1.99.1-7) ...
```

The mirror supports By-Hash:

```
$ wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease 2>/dev/null -O - | grep By-Hash
Acquire-By-Hash: yes
```

Any ideas how to make apt-get use that options? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual for [apt.conf(5)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/apt/apt.conf.5.en.html) says, for `Acquire::By-Hash`:

> Try to download **indexes** via an URI constructed from a hashsum of the expected file

(my emphasis)

In my testing the following worked as expected (after cleaning out `/var/lib/apt/lists`, which `apt clean` didn't seem to do a good job of). Since I have a local mirror I could verify the requested indexes from its log too:

```
apt{,-get} update -o Acquire::By-Hash="force" -o Debug::Acquire::http=true
```

so the manual is correct and accurate. Acquiring the packages themselves by hash is not supported, only the indexes.

Comment: Clean only clears archive files, not package lists.